# How to store the result of a substitution parameter/string?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to store the result of a substitution parameter/string? For example, I want to store the following output into a variable.

```js
console.log('%j', {foo: 123, bar: 'abc'});
```

**Output:**

```
{"foo":123,"bar":"abc"}
```

I already know `JSON.stringify` e.g.

```
const s = JSON.stringify({foo: 123, bar: 'abc'});
```

Comment: *"I already know JSON.stringify"* - then what's not working?

Comment: @Spectric - Instead of using `+` multiple times, I want to do something like `'%s %j %s'`.

Comment: Take a look at [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format)

Comment: @Thanks, A_A. I solved it exactly this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it this way:

```js
const x = 'json';
const y = 'string';
const s = `${JSON.stringify({foo: 123, bar: 'abc'})} is a ${x} ${y}`;
console.log(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%o` and you can see more details, other operators, in `console.log` following link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console

```js
console.log('test %o test', {foo: 123, bar: 'abc'});
```